# Difference between two buffers in C/C++

Tags: c, windows

This development is being done on Windows in usermode.

I have two (potentially quite large) buffers, and I would like to know the number of bytes different between the two of them.

I wrote this myself just checking byte by byte, but this resulted in a quite slow implementation. As I'm comparing on the order of hundreds of megabytes, this is undesirable. I'm aware that I could optimize this though many different means, but this seems like a common problem that's probably got optimized solutions already out there, and there's no way I'm going to optimize this as effectively as if it was written by optimization experts.

Perhaps my Googling is inadequate, but I'm unable to find any other C or C++ functions that can count the number of different bytes between two buffers. Is there such a built in function to the C standard library, WinAPI, or C++ standard library that I just don't know of? Or do I need to manually optimize this?

Comment: note that RtlCompareMemory stops after the first mismatch, it retunrs the number of matching bytes up to the first difference

Comment: You know, this is what SO should be for. Instead this is probably going to be closed as seeking library.

Comment: Ah, looks like you all caught it - `The RtlCompareMemory routine compares two blocks of memory and returns the number of bytes that match.` apparently means only bytes that match up to the first mismatch. Regardless, the question stands; is there a function that does what I'm looking for?

Comment: @JamesMcDowell you wrote it already. The reason yours is slower is because it’s actually doing what you want.

Comment: @Taekahn the windows function almost certainly does it in chunk of 4, 8 or 16 bytes. OP should do the same

Comment: @Taekahn In most cases (95%+), the buffers will be identical, so no, the slowdown definitely came from it being unoptimized.

Comment: @pm100 Optimization is a lot more than just that. There's cache alignment, execution port optimization, and all sorts of stuff I'm nowhere near experienced enough to adequately take advantage of.

Comment: you are also getting downvotes for saying c/c++ - folks hate that for some reason, and will go on long rants about it. People only want things tagged c++ if they are specifcally c++ - yours isnt

Comment: I was going to comment on that c/c++ thing, but this question is just as viable in either, so why bother?

Comment: My current optimization has me `memcmp`ing in relatively large chunks, then falling back to smaller chunks if it returns differences.

Comment: @JamesMcDowell yup but it will sure get a lot faster if you chunk it up - thats what memcmp implementations always do, and so long as you are doing a linear search the caches will cooperate with you

Comment: @pm100 valid reasons for people to not like combining the two, but this is one of the few posts that does it correctly. Upvoted.

Comment: @JamesMcDowell post your code on code review if you want to see if people have suggestions on how to improve it any further

Comment: @Taekahn Thanks, will do once I've it optimized as much as I can.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing this (perhaps somewhat poorly) optimized code to do the job for me. I was hoping it would vectorize this under the hood, but that doesn't appear to be happening unfortunately, and I didn't feel like digging around the SIMD intrinsics to do it manually. As a result, my bit fiddling tricks may end up making  it slower, but it's still fast enough that it's no more than about 4% of my code's runtime (and almost all of that was `memcmp`). Whether or not it could be better, it's good enough for me.

I'll note that this is designed to be fast for my use case, where I'm expecting only rare differences.

```
inline size_t ComputeDifferenceSmall(
    _In_reads_bytes_(size) char* buf1, 
    _In_reads_bytes_(size) char* buf2, 
    size_t size) {

    /* size should be <= 0x1000 bytes */
    /* In my case, I expect frequent differences if any at all are present. */
    size_t res = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < (size & ~0xF); i += 0x10) {
        uint64_t diff1 = *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(buf1) ^ 
            *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(buf2);
        if (!diff1) continue;

        /* Bit fiddle to make each byte 1 if they're different and 0 if the same */
        diff1 = ((diff1 & 0xF0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0ULL) >> 4) | (diff1 & 0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0FULL);
        diff1 = ((diff1 & 0x0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0CULL) >> 2) | (diff1 & 0x0303030303030303ULL);
        diff1 = ((diff1 & 0x0202020202020202ULL) >> 1) | (diff1 & 0x0101010101010101ULL);

        /* Sum the bytes */
        diff1 = (diff1 >> 32) + (diff1 & 0xFFFFFFFFULL);
        diff1 = (diff1 >> 16) + (diff1 & 0xFFFFULL);
        diff1 = (diff1 >> 8) + (diff1 & 0xFFULL);
        diff1 = (diff1 >> 4) + (diff1 & 0xFULL);

        res += diff1;
    }

    for (size_t i = (size & ~0xF); i < size; i++) {
        res += (buf1[i] != buf2[i]);
    }

    return res;
}

size_t ComputeDifference(
    _In_reads_bytes_(size) char* buf1, 
    _In_reads_bytes_(size) char* buf2, 
    size_t size) {

    size_t res = 0;

    /* I expect most pages to be identical, and both buffers should be page aligned if 
     * larger than a page. memcmp has more optimizations than I'll ever come up with, 
     * so I can just use that to determine if I need to check for differences 
     * in the page. */
    for (size_t pn = 0; pn < (size & ~0xFFF); pn += 0x1000) {
        if (memcmp(&buf1[pn], &buf2[pn], 0x1000)) {
            res += ComputeDifferenceSmall(&buf1[pn], &buf2[pn], 0x1000);
        }
    }

    return res + ComputeDifferenceSmall(
        &buf1[size & ~0xFFF], &buf2[size & ~0xFFF], size & 0xFFF);
}
```

Comment: From here on in, this sounds like a job for... [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking)! I linked to the help pages because you'll want to tweak your question to fit their requirements. I recommend including the CPU archetecture you're targettin so that the answerers can take advantage of the really sneaky bits.